# Can Drools' default stderr output be changed to INFO in stdout with debug event listeners?

Tags: drools, kie

I've added `Agenda` and `RuleRuntime` event listeners to my stateless KIE session but all outputs are showing as `ERROR [stderr] ...`; is it possible to configure the session/listeners to use `stdout` and control log levels (preferably `INFO`)?

I've seen an almost identical [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/9OWV_zqhAGA) question for KIE Execution Server but I'm embedding the drools engine in a Thorntail application.

I'm using stateless KIE Sessions and version `7.23.0.Final` of `org.kie.kie-api`, `org.kie.kie-cie`, `org.drools.drools-core`.  An excerpt of the creation of my stateless session is:

```java
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
StatelessKieSession statelessKieSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
statelessKieSession.addEventListener(new DebugAgendaEventListener());
statelessKieSession.addEventListener(new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener());
```

I noticed that one of the constructors on [DebugAgendaEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/event/rule/DebugAgendaEventListener.html) and [DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/event/rule/DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener.html) can accept a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html?is-external=true) argument, can I use this to replace the default `stderr`?

Sample outputs logged to the console are:

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ ...]]]
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[...]]]
... Rule fired ...
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ ... ]]]
```

I don't see why these are logged to `stderr` by default, they appear more `DEBUG`/`TRACE` level information so would like to have them output to `stdout` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Debug*Listener`(s) in kie-api by default emits to standard error to work regardless of any logging configuration. You can indeed pass a custom PrintStream to override where the emission of message is being printed, by using that constructor.

> is it possible to configure the session/listeners to use `stdout` and control log levels (preferably `INFO`)?

You can use `Debug*Listener`(s) in package `org.drools.core.event` from `drools-core` dependency, which by means of SLF4j works already by default in the way you describe, that is emit at `info` level by default. Provided that as default practice you have configured logging to emit to standard output, it will work that way out of the box.

These are just some "utility" default implementations; alternatively, you can implement your own Listener(s) to work in the you prefer best.